# ReactJs - Multiple Components - Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm new to react, and I am having trouble with multiple components.

This is the error I get **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

Code that I'm using.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtf1/t39.3284-6/11057100_835863049837306_1087123501_n.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="js/layout.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

layout.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Header from "./header";

class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return(
        <div>
           <Header/>
        </div>
    );
    }
}

const app = document.getElementById("app");
ReactDOM.render(<Layout/>, app);
```

And header.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <h1>Hello header</h1>
    );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Babel` handles only the transpilation part (i.e. converts es2015 and jsx syntax into valid ES5). But you still need to use either a bundler (webpack, browserify) or a module loader (systemjs or jspm) to load modules.

Here is an example using SystemJS. [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3zSGi5BHyx29fcUyEUrn?p=preview).

Configure systemjs loader to load libs from cdn

```
System.config({
    transpiler: 'babel',
    baseURL: '',
    map: {
      babel: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js',
      react: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js',
      'react-dom': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js'
    }
});

// load application
System.import('script.js');
```

Import local files

```
// inside script.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Header from "./header.js"; //note extension

class Layout extends React.Component {
```

Comment: Thank You! Working nicely :)